# Python - How to replace numbers variables

Tags: python, string

How to replace numbers  variables ?

works..

```
print("\033[1;1H TEXT")
```

not works..

```
x=10
y=20
print("\033[x;yH TEXT")
```

or how else do it? Thank yout

Comment: I don't really know anything about python however it looks to me like you added them into the print function as a string instead of concatenating them in.

Comment: Just as an aside, seems like you're trying to format code for the terminal. [There's libraries for that](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to build a string with the values of those variables? You can use `format` for this

```
>>> x = 10
>>> y = 20
>>> '\033[{};{}H TEXT'.format(x, y)
'\x1b[10;20H TEXT'
```

Edit:

Regarding how to replace `TEXT` you can do the same thing as above

```
'\033[{};{}H {}'.format(x, y, array[i])
```

Comment: Thank you. and dump box please? print '\033[{};{}H array[i]'.format(x+i, y)

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: How to replace TEXT to array[i]